# Moving media between blogs changes the URL subdirectory

Tags: media, import, export, wordpress.com-hosting, bulk-import

On wordpress.com, I'm exporting media from one blog and import it into another.

**Problem:** On the source blog, some media files are e.g. in Folder **"2014/02"**, but they get imported into folder **"2014/03"**. As a consequence, all links in posts to this particular file are lost and need to be re-edited.

The cause seems to be that some media files have been uploaded in **"February 2014"**, but they were published in **"March 2014"**

In the export XML file, you can clearly see that the original file  was located in **2014/02/1.png**. But since the publication date was in March 2014, it is getting imported into **2014/03/1.png**, which is another directory.

**Is there a way to import media files with the original URL location ?**

Here is an example export of one of such media files:

```
<item>
        <title>1</title>
        <link>https://xxx.wordpress.com/1-84/</link>
        <pubDate>Fri, 07 Mar 2014 12:21:21 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator>xxx</dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://xxx.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/1.png</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id>111</wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>2014-03-07 12:21:21</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>2014-03-07 12:21:21</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>closed</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>1-84</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>inherit</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>attachment</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
        <wp:attachment_url>https://xxx.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/1.png</wp:attachment_url>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_wp_attached_file</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[/home/wpcom/public_html/wp-content/blogs.dir/xxx/xxx/files/2014/02/1.png]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_wp_attachment_metadata</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:5:{s:5:"width";i:631;s:6:"height";i:631;s:4:"file";s:77:"/home/wpcom/public_html/wp-content/blogs.dir/xxx/xxx/files/2014/02/1.png";s:5:"sizes";a:0:{}s:10:"image_meta";a:10:{s:8:"aperture";i:0;s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";i:0;s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";i:0;s:3:"iso";i:0;s:13:"shutter_speed";i:0;s:5:"title";s:0:"";}}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
    </item>
```

Comment: This site only covers WordPress.org. Please see WordPress.com for help with that product as it's a whole nother ball of wax. :)